# Boosting definition clarification

Tags: boosting, ensemble-learning

Regarding boosting in the context of machine learning. One definition I have encountered talks about turning multiple weak learners into one strong learner, and another talks about starting with a prediction and iteratively improving it by learning predictors for residuals (such as gradient boosting).

**The questions I have are:**

- Which definition is more accurate? (or are they equivalent?)
- Does the second simply implement the first?
- What is the formal definition in the literature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Both definitions are reasonable working definitions and equally valid as they capture the iterative nature of boosting algorithms. I view the first one as more general because the iterative nature of boosting *was not* strictly speaking a requirement early on. Originally boosting was defined with respect to [PAC learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning) in Schapire (1990) ["The strength of weak learnability"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00116037). To quote directly from the 2012 monograph ["Boosting: Foundations and Algorithms"](https://direct.mit.edu/books/oa-monograph/5342/BoostingFoundations-and-Algorithms) by Schapire and Freund: "*Boosting has its roots in a theoretical framework for studying machine learning called the PAC model, proposed by Valiant, (...)*" and "*the key idea behind boosting is to choose training sets for the base learner in such a fashion as to force it to infer something new about the data each time it is called.*"
2. Not necessarily. For example, AdaBoost learns predictors for the sample points *weighted by* the residuals, not *for* the residuals (as would be the case for gradient boosting for example). That said, both gradient boosting and AdaBoost utilise weak learners to iteratively update their overall predictions "*turning multiple weak learners into one strong learner*". CV.SE has a very good thread on: *[In boosting, why are the learners "weak"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/)*  that discusses this matter in more detail.
3. There is no good concise formal definition. Since Breiman's 1998 ["Arcing classifier (with discussion and a rejoinder by the author)"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-26/issue-3/Arcing-classifier-with-discussion-and-a-rejoinder-by-the-author/10.1214/aos/1024691079.full) we have moved away from the ensemble methods view to the functional gradient descent view; Friedman's 2001 ["Greedy function approximation: A gradient boosting machine"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-29/issue-5/Greedy-function-approximation-A-gradient-boosting-machine/10.1214/aos/1013203451.full) being pretty much the theoretical blue-print for all boosting algorithms after it. This numerical optimization in function space necessitates looking at boosting as an iterative procedure; the "*incremental functions*" learned are the "*boosts*" and we thus have a "stage-wise" update where each stage uses a suitable approximation to our loss function $L$ to search for its next "boost".

Something like: "Boosting refers to the greedy stage-wise updates done to a prediction function $F$ using weak learners $h$ in order to minimise a specified loss function $L$." is probably the most informal and succinct one can think of... (i.e. trying to put Eqs (9 & 10) from Friedman's 2001 into words.)

Comment: Hi, thanks! That made everything much clear. Regarding (2), what I'm asking is whether predicting the residuals is a private case of the way boosting is defined as weak learners converted to a strong learner. AdaBoost is a different case (not predicting the residuals) - that I understand. But what about Gradient Boosting for instance? Does it have something to do with weak and strong learners?

Comment: I am happy I could help. Yes, GB has to do with weak learners too. I will amend the main answer to also clarify that point there.