# Can we use any learners in gradient boosting instead of trees?

Tags: boosting, cart, gradient

As we are simply trying to predict residuals from weak learners and aggregating them, can we use any weak learners in gradient boosting machines instead of trees ? 
If so, why are the all the gbm implementations like xgboost, lightgbm use trees ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use learners besides trees. [XGBoost implements linear learners](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) in addition to trees.

Trees are nice because weak learners can be aggregated to become strong learners. We have several posts about this.

- [In boosting, why are the learners "weak"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23388/in-boosting-why-are-the-learners-weak)
- [On the "strength" of weak learners](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/on-the-strength-of-weak-learners)